# Largest known non-pandigital Carmichael-number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, carmichael-numbers

This Carmichaelnumber with $39$ digits $$145410193191244273054310497291961592961$$ is not pandigital , the digit $8$ is missing.

> What is the largest known Carmichael-number not being pandigital (with at least one digit missing in the decimal expansion) ?

Comment: $$502968961661095567282810561851297609678229070560076298749007885246826871726668089189601$$ is an example with $87$ digits. Digit $3$ is missing.

Comment: [factordb](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000004649945177)

Comment: An example with $97$ digits , $5$ missing , is $$1200678011889802716621401397429179829919803917070231914778418048382642472819240078429963681472321$$

Comment: [factordb](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000004649963265)

Comment: The number $n=(6k+1)(12k+1)(18k+1)$ with k equal to `294555313376703770324072440550486` has $101$ digits and is a Carmichael number (it misses the digit $7$). Another $101$-digit example for n can be constructed in the same way with k equal to `202826390084431567861373760569275`, missing the digit $6$.

Comment: Using the same format `k=901966164698621693452028481838495` gives an $102$-digit $n$ with the digit $6$ missing.

Comment: @jorisperrenet I used the same idea because it is the best way to quickly construct many Carmichael numbers. I wonder whether there are infinite many such Carmichael numbers.

Comment: Again, using the same format `k=77827388506854892505748442714276512918005` gives a $126$-digit Carmichael number with missing digit $2$.